# Update Contact MiddleName field on Form Load - MS CRM 2011 Plugin

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I've started MS CRM development few days ago and i spend hours today on this very simple basic operation and didn't had much luck finding what i'm doing wrong.

I want to update a Middle Name of a contact entity, upon creating the record. And that i can do with following code.

But now i wants to do the same thing when I open up a contact record. I did register a new step on Retrieve Message under contact Entity. But its not working.. no exceptions are thrown.

```cs
    public class IzzyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));

            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);


            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                Entity currentEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];


                if (currentEntity.Attributes.Contains("middlename"))
                {
                    currentEntity.Attributes["middlename"] = "Middle name changed";
                }
                else
                {
                    currentEntity.Attributes.Add("middlename", "Middle name changed");
                }

                service.Update(currentEntity);


            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(f.ToString());
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you sure the plugin is firing? It looks ok to me. Replace your code with a simple throw new Exception() and verify that the operation is cancelled when you try to create a contact through the UI.

Comment: I did this. Exception thrown as expected. However would you be able to answer the updated question.

Answer (score 2):

Can you not use javascript on page load to set the middlename value when the record is opened? Would be a lot easier IMO

Something like this onload would work

Xrm.Page.getAttribute('middlename').setValue('New Middle Name');

If you need to calculate the middle name from other fields in the same entity, you may want to refer to the [XRM Page documentation on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334351.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to do this using JavaScript. I don't think you can register a plugin that can be triggered when opening a record.

Comment: Hi, what does Retrieve message do? I thought it triggers when we are loading a Record

Comment: It does. You can register a plugin on Retrieve, it's just got the potential to significantly hit performance.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not going to question why you want to do this or where you will get a value for your middle name, however I suspect the issue is around sequencing of your plugins/updates. It's not really a good idea to write plugins against the `Retrieve` message as they get called so frequently. Personally i think that JScript is the way to go,  but...

If you want to insert a value into `middlename` and just return this to the user on Retrieve but *without* commiting this to the database (I know this wasn't your exact question) then:

1. Register your plugin on the **Post-operation** of the Retrieve message
2. in your code put this:

```cs
>     Entity currentEntity = (Entity)context.OutputParameters["Entity"];
>     if(currentEntity.Attributes.contains("middlename"){
>         currentEntity["middlename"] = "New value";    
>     }else{
>         currentEntity.Attributes.Add("middlename","New value");
>     }
```

If you want to insert a value into `middlename` and return this to the user on Retrieve **and** commit this to the database then I suspect you will need to combine both into a single plugin registered on pre- and post-operation of Retrieve and then do something like this (but I'm very wary of even attempting an Update on every Retreive...!):

```cs
public class IzzyPlugin : IPlugin
{
    public void Execute(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        try
        {
            IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
            IOrganizationServiceFactory factory = (IOrganizationServiceFactory)serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IOrganizationServiceFactory));
            IOrganizationService service = factory.CreateOrganizationService(context.UserId);

            if (context.InputParameters.Contains("Target") && context.InputParameters["Target"] is Entity)
            {
                var middleNameValue = "Middle name changed";
                Entity currentEntity;

                // Pre-stage plugin
                if(context.Stage < 30){
                    currentEntity = (Entity)context.InputParameters["Target"];

                    if (currentEntity.Attributes.Contains("middlename"))
                    {
                        currentEntity.Attributes["middlename"] = middleNameValue;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        currentEntity.Attributes.Add("middlename", middleNameValue);
                    }
                    service.Update(currentEntity);
                }else{
                    currentEntity = (Entity)context.OutputParameters["Entity"];
                    if(currentEntity.Attributes.contains("middlename"){
                        currentEntity["middlename"] = middleNameValue;    
                    }else{
                        currentEntity.Attributes.Add("middlename",middleNameValue);
                    }                   
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception f)
        {
            throw new InvalidPluginExecutionException(f.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```